# SOLVED - Magento 2 Get product_options value from sales_order_item

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-options, order-items

In **sales_order_item** table, there's a column **product_options** to store some custom values.

I need to get the **deliverydates** from the following value (value from the db column **product_options**)

```
{"info_buyRequest":{"qty":"1","super_attribute":{"137":"2803","93":"17717"},"product":"37702","deliverydates":"2018-04-07"}}
```

I have tried the following code, but is not working.

```
    foreach ($this->order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
        $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions(); 
        #$options = $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($orderItem->getProduct());
        if(!empty($options['options'])) {        
            foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
                if ($option['label'] == 'deliverydates'){
                    $deliverydate = $option['value'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your json, you cannot get the delivery dates by **options** key, you have to use **info_buyRequest**, Try this

```
foreach ($this->order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
     $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions(); 
        if(!empty($options['info_buyRequest'])) {
            if(!empty($options['info_buyRequest']["deliverydates"])) {
                $deliverydates = $options['info_buyRequest']["deliverydates"];
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code. I got an error "Notice: Undefined index: info_buyRequest.". it seems info_buyRequest is empty. I've checked in my DB again, I'm sure the data is there as the JSON data i posted in the answer. I'm don't know why it didn't get me the productOptions.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, Please try to use [        $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions(); ] instead of    [$options = $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($orderItem->getProduct());] , If you are working on the order you need to use [ $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();] same as your code hope this will help

Comment: I am glad that i could help you

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code to get all configurable product options from order

```
   $opts=array();
   $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
      foreach ($items as $item) 
      {       
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();          
        if (isset($options['attributes_info']) && !empty($options['attributes_info'])) 
        {             
        foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $option) 
        {      
             $opts[strtolower($option['label'])] = $option['value'];   
        }

        }
      }
   print_r($opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get product attribute for product items in Order.

```
$orderAllItems = $this->order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderAllItems as $orderItem) {
    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
    if ($options) {
        $info = $options['info_buyRequest'];
    }
}
```

You can get all custom options from `$info`.